# elasticsearch: resyncing the indexes from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have following situation need some help:

- running mongodb replicaSet with 3 instances having multiple dbs and collections
- running elasticsearch
- in order to trigger sync between elasticsearch and mongodb i run the following command
  `>mongo-connector -m 127.0.0.1:27017 -t 127.0.0.1:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager`
  And it worked perfectly all the data from mongodb synced to elasticsearch nice and sweet.
- things were working in perfect harmony....
- till the time i deleted all indices from elastic search for resolving another problem.

Problem: As i deleted all the indices from my elasticsearch.  when i re run this command `>mongo-connector -m 127.0.0.1:27017 -t 127.0.0.1:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager`
it doesnt sync data from mongodb to elasticsearch. I also tried 
`mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager -n {db}.{collection_name} -g {djangodb}.{spiderCollection1}` But it doesnt work.

What can i do to retrigger the sync of collections/documents in elasticsearch from mongodb?
Or how can i perform re-syncing of data from mongodb to elasticsearch

no versions of db or elasticsearch has been changed/modified.

Will appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Worked, by recreating the db in the mongodb again. 
But if any one knows anyother alternative workaround, please feelfree to share without having to create the db again in mongodb.
thanks,